# django how to dynamically create nested and or queries

Tags: django

I have two types of filter list looking like below

```
a_filter = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b_filter = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I have to combine the `in` query for `a_filter` and boolean field query for `b_filter` something like below

```
Item.objects.filter(a__in=a_filter, x=True, y=True, z=True)
```

How do I dynamically create this query? I got as far as below

```
filters = {
  a_filter__in:a_filter,
}

and_condition = Q(**filters)

if len(b_filter) > 0:
  or_cond = Q()
  for filter in b_filter:
    or_cond.add(Q(**{filter:True}), Q.AND)

and_condition.add(or_filter)

Item.objects.filter(and_condition)
```

This create additional `(OR: (AND: )` in between the two filter queries like below

```
(AND: 'a_filter__in': ['a', 'b', 'c'), (OR: (AND: ), (AND:('x':True, 'y':True, 'z':True))
```

How do I write a correctly working query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Q` objects to get the specific query you cited.

This would be enough:

```
bool_kwargs = {k: True for k in b_filter}
Item.objects.filter(a__in=a_filter, **bool_kwargs)
```

Also, the example you gave would not work. Assuming you had in mind something like:

```
filters = {
    "a__in": a_filter,
}

and_condition = Q(**filters)

if len(b_filter) > 0:
    or_cond = Q()
    for filter in b_filter:
        or_cond.add(Q(**{filter: True}), Q.AND)

    and_condition.add(or_cond)

Item.objects.filter(and_condition)
```

If you want to use `Q` objects anyway or that `Q.AND` is supposed to be `Q.OR` (as hinted by the `or_cond` variable name), you can do:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_ # replace or_ with and_ for Q.AND

bool_q_list = [Q(k=True) for k in b_filter]
bool_q = reduce(or_, bool_q_list) # replace or_ with and_ for Q.AND
Item.objects.filter(bool_q, a__in=a_filter)
```